# How to distinguish liaisons correctly?

Tags: pronunciation, listening

1)

> …, so he **tried to** find a qualified pilot to guide him.

The "d" sound  in "tried" is dropped so if there was no context provided, It might be perceived to be,

> He **try to** find a qualified pilot to guide him.

2)

> He wen**t a**shore.

This might be understood as,

> He wen**t to** shore.

3)

In some cases, contraction can also be ambiguous. This "d" can mean either "had" or "would."

> She'**d** cut the loaf into five slices.

How to interpret liaisons like those in a right way?

*Original listening material of example(1) and example(2): [A Qualified Pilot](https://soundcloud.com/a_learner/a-qualified-pilot).*

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. I have known how to distinguish example (2) and (3) now. But I still can't find the "d" sound in example (1). Here's the original listening material: https://soundcloud.com/a_learner/a-qualified-pilot

Answer (score 1):

Each of your examples has a different answer.

---

In example (1) it would be grammatically incorrect to say **he try to find**.  This is not the type of mistake native speakers ever make, so it can only be **he tried to find**.

---

In example (2) the two sentences you list are likely (but not certain) to be pronounced differently in American English.  In the sentence

> He went ashore

the t may be stopped in the throat, not a plosive t.

> He went to shore

Here we have the throat-stopped t followed by a plosive t on the to.

Of course, exactly how people pronounce these things depends on the accent being used and how quickly and clearly they are speaking.  It is conceivable that in a noisy environment, one might have a hard time distinguishing the two, but then, they mean the same thing anyway.

---

In example (3) the only way to know whether **she'd** means **she would** or **she had** is from the context, but these two are unlikely to be confused because they require very different contexts.

**She had** is used to describe something she did only once in the past and then we discuss something that happens after.

> **She'd** already **cut** the loaves in five places when she realized she had forgotten to add salt.

**She would** refers to something she did over and over in the past

> I used to order from her deli every day.  **She'd cut** the loaves in five places, just like I like them.